# Conditional expectation, indication function

Tags: probability, expectation

I am given that $X,Y$ are independent Bernoulli RVs with parameter $p\in (0,1)$. I am also told $Z=1_{(X+Y=0)}$. I am asked to find $E[X\mid Z]$ and $E[Y\mid Z]$.

I can see that the expected values are going to be equivalent, but I'm not quite sure how to compute these expectations. Could someone give me a hint?
Thanks.
Harry

Comment: Hint: X and Z are $______$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we are calculating 
$$
E[X \mid Z] = \sum_x xP(X=x \mid Z=z)
$$
For the Bernoulli variable this will be just
$$
\begin{align}
E[X \mid Z] &= 1 \cdot P(X=1 \mid Z=z) + 0 \cdot  P(X=0 \mid Z=z)\\
 &=P(X=1 \mid Z=z)
\end{align}
$$
If $Z=1$ then clearly both $X$ and $Z$ are zero, so $P(X=1 \mid Z=1)=0$. In the other case we have
$$
\begin{align}
P(X=1 \mid Z=0) &= \frac{ P(X=1, Z=0)}{P(Z=0)}\\
 &=\frac{P(X=1 \cap  (X=1 \cup Y=1))}{P(X=1 \cup Y=1)}
 \\
&=\frac{P(X=1)}{1-P(X=0 \cap Y=0)}\\
&=\frac{p}{1-(1-p)^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{2-p}
\end{align}
$$
So final answer is

$$ E[Y \mid Z]=E[X \mid Z] = \left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}   0  & \mbox{for } Z=1 \\ \frac{1}{2-p}
 & \mbox{for } Z=0  \end{array} \right. $$

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting. Can one show that,

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[X+Y\vert 1_{\{X+Y=0\}}] &= \frac{\mathbb{E}[(X+Y)1_{\{X+Y=0\}}]}{\mathbb{P}[X+Y=0]} \\
&= \frac{0}{(1-p)^2} \\
&= 0
\end{align*}
$$

It does not seem like $X$ and $1_{\{X+Y=0\}}$ can be independent since if the indicator is unity, we know $X$ is 0. I'm asking not stating. :)